# Занесение данных из массива в таблицу. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет! Нужна помощь с занесением данных из массива в таблицу.
Есть код:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal/Modal'



const products = [
  {
    count: '1',
    product: 'FirstProduct',
    key: 1
  },
  {
    count: '1',
    product: 'SecondProduct',  
    key: 2
  },
]

function App() {
  


  return ( 
   <div >
     <header></header>
     <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Тестовый магазин</h1>
     <div>

       <Modal/>
    <table>
     <tr>
       <th colspan="1">Наименование</th>
       <th>Количество</th>
     </tr>
         <tr>
       <td>Первый товар</td>
       <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
       <td>Второй товар</td>
       <td>1</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     </div>

     </div>
     );
}

export default App
```

Помогите сделать так, чтобы таблица забирала значения из массива, а так же была возможность вносить в дальнейшем из модалки новые элементы. При этом вносила их только в часть после наименования и количества, т.е сюда =>
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По возможности разъясните как можно подробнее свой ответ, чтобы я смогла понять, а то гугл мне не особо помог)

Comment: Пацаны, научите меня реакту

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @Lukas,  я же говорю не особо помогает) 
У меня нет понимание того, как по циклу прогнать все значения массива в разные <tr>)

Comment: @АлинаСотская, https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-elgamal-n53hu?file=/src/App.js